# how to improve solution generated by greedy method for 0-1 knapsack?

Tags: optimization, np-hard

I am working on 0-1 knapsack using greedy method, I have some problem in it. It's already proved that solution generated by greedy method for 0-1 knapsack is may or may not be optimal. If solution generated by greedy method is not optimal then Please tell me how i can improve solution so that solution generated is optimal.

Comment: This is a very well studied problem with a standard dynamic programming solution. What reading did you do to try to find the answer yourself?

Comment: I know dynamic programming solution is optimal, but space & Time complexity is more. To overcome this drawback I am working on greedy. I am Trying to get the new idea so it will improve the solution generated by greedy method & overcome the drawback of dynamic programming.

Comment: 1. Please don't post the same comment multiple times.  2. Please include information in your question about what you've tried, what approaches you considered, why you rejected them, and  what attempt you've made on your own.  On this site we expect you to make a serious effort on your own before asking, and to show us in the question what you tried and where you got stuck.  In this case, apparently you already knew about the dynamic programming solution and don't want it, but you didn't mention this in the question.  This made people waste their time mentioning it to you.

Comment: @AmolBole So you are asking how to solve an NP-complete problem in polynomial time? Many famous people have failed to find an answer to that question.

Answer (score 2):

0/1 Knapsack is an NP-hard problem which has pseudopolynomial time algorithms. This means that if the weights are allowed to be large, then there is no hope of always finding the optimal solution, while if they are small, then there is an algorithm, in this case a dynamic programming algorithm.

From a practical point of view, real-world instances may not represent the worst case, and so there is some hope that heuristics will work in most cases, though I'm not sure there is a simple criterion for when you have achieved the optimal solution; so even if these heuristics are very good, you wouldn't be able to tell.